# Store and query user preferences (name/value pair) in a list with enum types and LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, enums, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have some user-configurable settings I want to save in SQL Server and query/manipulate with LINQ:

```
public enum PreferenceType
{
    NamePublic,
    EmailPublic,
    BirthdayPublic,
    Visibility
}
```

The first three are booleans but `Visibility` I would like to be its own enum...

```
public enum Visibility
{
    Normal,
    Hidden,
    FriendsOnly
}
```

I have member data in classes like:

```
public class Preference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PreferenceType Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    [...]
    public virtual ICollection<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
}
```

In my data context:

```
public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
```

Now that we're all set up, is this even possible? I want to be able to easily save and access the values of those user preferences, in queries and elsewhere. For instance:

```
List<Member> query = Members.Where(m =>
    m.Preferences.Any(v => v.Type == PreferenceType.Visibility
    && (Visibility)Enum.Parse(typeof(Visibility), v.Value) == Visibility.Normal));
```

Am I on the right track at all, or even close? Is what I want to do even possible? If not, what is the best practice for storing and retrieving various user preferences in a database with LINQ, considering they may be different data types? Do I just have to go to a simple name/value pair with strings for everything?